# Using Jquery to fade in text and display each one at a time from JSON file

Tags: jquery, json

I would like to fade-in text from a JSON file.  Right now I can only output all of the names from the JSON file.  I want to be able to display one name at a time and have the next name fade in.  How can I do this?

data.json:

```
[{"name" : "Bill"},{"name" : "George"},{"name" : "Mike"},{"name" : "Stan"}]
```

script.js:

```
    $(document).ready(function () { // load json file using jquery ajax
    $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
        var output = '<p>';
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            output += '<p>' + val.name + '<br/>';
        });
        $('#text').html(output); // replace all existing content
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="text"></div>

<script>
(function() {
    var names = $("#text");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextName() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        names.eq(quoteIndex % names.length)
            .fadeIn(300)
            .delay(300)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextName);
    }
    showNextName();
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code provided your actual HTML output will look like this:

```
<div id="text">
  <p>Bill</p>
  <p>George</p>
  <p>Mike</p>
  <p>Stan</p>
</div>
```

Then what you need is hide all **p** tags and then target each `p` inside `#text` to fadeIn, try this:

```
$(function() {
    var quoteIndex = 0;
    function showNextName() {
        $('#text p').eq(quoteIndex)
            .fadeIn(700, showNextName);
        quoteIndex++
    }
    showNextName();
});
```

**Check the snippet**

```js
$(function() {
    var quoteIndex = 0;
    function showNextName() {
        $('#text p').eq(quoteIndex).fadeIn(700, showNextName);
        quoteIndex++
    }
    showNextName();
});
```

```css
#text p {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">
  <p>Bill</p>
  <p>George</p>
  <p>Mike</p>
  <p>Stan</p>
</div>
```

---

> EDIT

**To see just one name on page**

```js
$(function() {
    var quoteIndex = 0,
        nup        = $('#text p').length;
    function showNextName() {
        $('#text p').eq(quoteIndex)
                    .fadeIn(700)
                    .delay(500)
                    .fadeOut(400, showNextName)
        if (quoteIndex >= nup-1) {
          quoteIndex=0
        } else {
          quoteIndex++
        }
    }
    showNextName();
});
```

```css
#text p {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">
  <p>Bill</p>
  <p>George</p>
  <p>Mike</p>
  <p>Stan</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is close. What I am looking for is to replace the first name with the second name and so on.  So Bill would show first, then fade away into George and so on then loop and do all over again.

Comment: @childy and when the last is reached ... stay there or loop again ?

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  How do I get the names from the JSON file?

Comment: @childy your actual code will work I just avoid that here to recreate the html output

Comment: This is where I get lost. In my script.js file I can get the JSON data and output each name in it's own <p> tag. How do I put this data into your function to show only one name at a time?

Comment: @childy Just print all of them with your actual code inside #text and hide it with CSS

Comment: When I run my script.js file the output is all four names.  How can I just have one at a time appear?

Comment: @childy hide all with CSS ... add this on the CSS `#text p {
  display:none;
}`

Comment: Yes, I did that but nothing shows.  The problem is I need to pull data from an external JSON file.  So my script.js file isn't outputting the data correctly with the function you created.  I need help with my script.js file.  Thanks.

Comment: @childy please replicate your actual code calling the json on jsfiddle or codepen to help U

Comment: Here is what I have so far - https://jsfiddle.net/childy/t7jfdntz/1/#&togetherjs=vktmGcFk8z